# 'comparison between pointer and integer' error for Phone Directory program

Tags: c

So I'm pretty new too C, and programming. I'm learning little by little. A friend of mine gave me a good idea for a first project. The goal is too allow the user too select a department (Phone Directory for a Casino), and once that department has been selected, it will show all the numbers for that department.

Eventually I want too add more too this, but for now, I'm going too keep it simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
   printf("Please Select Department [Security, Food & Beverage, Hotel]\n");

   char str[20];

   gets(str);

   if (gets(str) == 8)
   {
       printf("You have selected Security\n");
       printf("218-760-1122, 218-760-5564\n");
   }

   else if (gets(str) == 5)
   {
       printf("You have Selected Hotel\n");
       printf("218-443-9810");
   }

   else if (gets(str) == 15)
   {
       printf("You have selected Security\n");
       printf("218-550-9818, 218-443-1231\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The problem with this program is when I compile and build the program, it prints the "selection" part of the script, where get(str) is used. After I select which one I would like too use, it goes blank, and nothing is displayed, but the script itself is still running.

I'm really new too this, and I'm assuming its something too do with how I'm determining which department is selected, in the if/else statements. I cant seem too figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried different solutions, usually getting different results, the closest being by adding a semi-colon too the last line of the else if statement, which runs the script, skips the first two else statements, and prints the security code.

3 warnings pop up for lines 10, 16, and 22

warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

This is a learning experience for me, and I would appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: Don't use `gets`. Never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's a dangerous function that is prone to buffer overflows, which is why it has been removed from the C standard. And you don't even use it correctly. Use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, and *read its documentation!*

Comment: So, if you look at a documentation of `gets()`, you will see two things. 1.) it returns a pointer (does that ring a bell regarding the error you're getting?) 2.) it's broken and removed from current C, as already mentioned :)

Comment: `gets()` doesn't return the length of the string.  I think you're looking for `strlen()`.  Also, `gets()` shouldn't be used anyway, and a string comparison with `strcmp()` or a related function would be better than just checking the length.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the feedback! I had not idea it wasn't even in use anymore.

Comment: Regarding checking only the length, what if I enter `abcde` as input? That's five characters, and will match your "Hotel" entry.

Comment: @Koquan - it is so insecure and so prone to exploit through buffer overrun it has been banished for use by only those that don't know any better. (which if this was suggested by your teacher really calls his (or her) credentials into question...)

Answer (score 1):

So, the first and most important error is already in the comments, but repeating it here for completeness:

**Do not use `gets()`!** It is broken and therefore removed from the current C standard. With `gets()`, you have no control over how much input is actually read, so any buffer can overflow (and attackers will use that). The replacement is `fgets()`, which has a size argument.

Note the same holds for things like `scanf("%s", ...)`. If you ever need to use a conversion to a string with the `scanf` family of functions, make sure to read the documentation, it tells you how to use a *field width*.

Back to your code, assuming you use `fgets()` like you should:

```
char str[20];

fgets(str, 20, stdin);

if (fgets(str, 20, stdin) == 8)
{
```

You have two errors here:

1. You call `fgets()` twice. Each call will attempt to read a line of input and store it in `str`. That's not what you want.
2. `fgets()` doesn't return the length but a pointer to `str` **if it was successfull**. If it failed, it returns `NULL`

So, the code should start like this:

```
char str[256];

if (!fgets(str, 256, stdin))
{
    fputs("Error reading input.", stderr);
    return 1;
}
```

Only after that error check, you should examine the **contents** of `str`, ie, what the user actually entered.

Note I also increased buffer size. People might enter longer lines by accident and there's really no need to be that tight with bytes nowadays.

Finally, just checking the length probably isn't a good idea. Instead, include `string.h` and use the [`strcmp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) function.